# Adding overlay / tile to map

Tags: openstreetmap

I have a website, http://airport-metars.ddns.net that gets data from FAA and plots on a map using Python and Folium.  The HTML page for the map is created by Python and Folium.  But I would like to add http://vfrmap.com to my map instead.  How can I do that?  I asked this question on openstreetmap.org and they recommended that I ask here.

https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/71287/adding-overlay-or-tile

I already have an API from vfrmap.com

Comment: I forgot to mention this, but I already have an API from http://vfrmap.com/

Comment: Anyone?  I'm stuck on this.

Comment: Looks like you just have to add a `TileLayer` with `http://vfrmap.com/20191010/tiles/vfrc/` as XYZ tile source. What have you tried so far? Also make sure to comply with [vrfmap's terms of service](http://vfrmap.com/tos.html).